# How do i install ubuntu 12.04 from a bootable usb pen drive?

Tags: 12.04, boot, windows-7

I have made my pen drive bootable. I am 100% sure there's nothing wrong with the pen drive.
I have a DELL inspiron n5010, I had tried installing ubuntu 12.04 four months back but I dont remember where i went wrong. 
When i boot my laptop and enter the boot menu ( by pressing the f12 key ) I don't get an option to boot from usb. What do I do?

Comment: In the BIOS menu, you need to change the boot order so that the USB flash drive, which is usually called USB-HDD in newer computers, is the first entry in the boot sequence, and then save your new BIOS settings and exit the BIOS setup.

Answer (score 0):

First, download the Ubuntu installer image.

Then, on Windows:

1. Download and run the [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer)

Or, on Mac:

1. Convert the `.iso` image file to a `.img` using `hdiutil`

   ```
   hdiutil convert /path/to/ubuntu.iso -format UDRW -o /path/to/target.img
   ```
2. Transfer the `.img` to the USB drive

   ```
    dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/diskN bs=1m
   ```

See: [Instructions for installing Ubuntu from a USB drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick).